# Не получается сделать навигацию с использованием $_GET

Tags: php

Пытаюсь сделать, чтобы подсвечивалась текущая страничка на сайте:

```html
<div id="nav">
   <ul>
      <li>
          <a <?php echo ($_GET['page'] == 'index' || !isset($_GET[page])) ? "class='active'" : ""; ?>
href="index1.php">Главная</a>
     </li>
      <li>
          <a <?php echo ($_GET['page'] == 'news') ? "class='active'" : ""; ?>
href="index2.php">Новости</a>
     </li>
      <li>
          <a <?php echo ($_GET['page'] == 'about') ? "class='active'" : ""; ?>
href="index3.php">О сайте</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

При запуске показывает ошибку

Undefined index: page

Подскажите, как можно исправить? Вариант с JS пока не рассматриваю, со скриптом навигация по сайту перестает работать))))

Comment: Я бы советовал использовать `filter_input()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте так

```
<?php
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 'index';
?>
<div id="nav">
   <ul>
      <li>
          <a <?php echo ($page == 'index' ? "class='active'" : ""); ?>
href="index1.php">Главная</a>
     </li>
      <li>
          <a <?php echo ($page == 'news' ? "class='active'" : ""); ?>
href="index2.php">Новости</a>
     </li>
      <li>
          <a <?php echo ($page == 'about' ? "class='active'" : ""); ?>
href="index3.php">О сайте</a>
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!! :))

Comment: Проблема решается еще проще, просто выключается контроль ошибок))))

Comment: @$_GET['page']... и не надо мудрить

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$pages = [
    'index' => '',
    'news'  => '',
    'about' => '',
];
if (isset($_GET['page']) && isset($pages[$_GET['page']])) {
    $idx = $_GET['page'];
} else {
    $idx = 'index';
}
$pages[$idx] = 'class="active" ';
?>
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a <?=$pages['index']?>href="index1.php">Главная</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a <?=$pages['news']?>href="index2.php">Новости</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a <?=$pages['about']?>href="index3.php">О сайте</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка ***Undefined index: page*** говорит о том, что у массива $_GET неправильный индекс, а неправильный он вот здесь --> `!isset($_GET[page])` , т.е. забыл поставить ковычки. Надо так `!isset($_GET['page'])`

Comment: Извините, это моя невнимательность( в коде, который запускаю, все кавычки стоят. А ошибку показывает, потому что изначально $_GET не существует